# In scale, the bottom blurred element overlaps the scaled element

Tags: css

**Goal:** The scaled element is not overlapped by the bottom element.

**Problem:** With a css `transition`, I `scale` up an element. In the parent element, the content above and below the child element is blurred. But unfortunately the lower blur effect overlaps the forgotten container.

**Question** What do I have to do so that the blur effect does not overlay the scaled container?

*Note:* `z-index` had no effect on me.

**My stack** Linux / Firefox

**My code**

```css
.container>*:not(.box) {
  background: black;  
  filter: blur(8px);  
  transition: filter 1s, background 1s;  
  filter: blur(8px); 
}
.box {
  padding: 40px 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: gray; 
  text-align:center;
  transition: scale 1s, background 1s, filter 1s;   
}
.box:focus-within {
  transition: scale 1s, background 1s; 
  scale: 1.8;
  background: lightblue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some text againsome text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again</p>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <input >
      <input >
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>some text againsome text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again</p>
  <input >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` (to create a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)) along with a `z-index` (which you can educate yourself on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)):

```css
.container>*:not(.box) {
  background: black;  
  filter: blur(8px);  
  transition: filter 1s, background 1s;  
  filter: blur(8px); 
}
.box {
  padding: 40px 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: gray; 
  text-align:center;
  transition: scale 1s, background 1s, filter 1s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box:focus-within {
  transition: scale 1s, background 1s; 
  scale: 1.8;
  background: lightblue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some text againsome text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again</p>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <input >
      <input >
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>some text againsome text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again</p>
  <input >
</div>
```

Comment: do you think it makes a difference if i set the container or just the box position:relative? From the point of view of browser resources?

Comment: I have no information on that, but honestly I also wouldn't care.

Answer (score 0):

Normally CSS acts wierdly when you place elements from top to bottom without any of them  having  z-index, so in your code when you click input, top side of your box which normally(before scale) first p element stays there, does not have blur but bottom side(second p element) have blur.

So it acts like even if you do not add z index to any element

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="firstPelement">some text againsome text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again</p>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <input >
      <input >
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="secondPelement">some text againsome text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again some text again</p>
  <input >
</div>
```

.firstPelement   -> z-index 0

.box             -> z-index 1

.secondPelement  -> z-index 2

That is why top side is not blurred but bottom side is blurred but when you add z-index to

```
.box{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

any element it acts like now all of them have z-index:0 but only .box have z-index:1

Question:
do you think it makes a difference if i set the container or just the box position:relative?

If you add z-index to your container all of the elements have z-index:1 but still the same inside z-index rule happens to them top is not blurry but bottom is blured