# How to pass a CSS variable correctly in nth-child?

Tags: css

**Goal:** Successfully pass a variable as a parameter to nth-child. In the example below, the third line should turn green.

**Problem:** Currently the parameter is ignored as a variable.

**Question:** Is this possible at all? If yes, what do I have to change?

**Example Code:**

```css
:root {
  --n: 3;
}
div p:nth-child(var(--n)) {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not possible

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for Comment. Maybe with Javascript?

Comment: @MaikLowrey with pure js you could do : `document.querySelector(\`div p:nth-child(${n})\`).classList.add("bg-green");` and define a CSS rule for the `bg-green` class.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your comment.  I'm still shocked that it doesn't work with vanilla CSS. I would not have thought.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Does anyone know why it is not possible?

Comment: because CSS variables are not designed to work that way.

Comment: What is the use case here? May be there is a better alternate for what you _actually_ want to do.

Comment: @SalmanA You are right, the use case is a bit more complex. I tried to keep it as abstract as possible to avoid slipping into an XY problem. The use case was to set up a toggle for a table that hides or displays a certain number of rows. I am able to solve it with javascript, but the question came up if I can replace the root variable "-n+2" to -n+6 with JS for example. I already went the other way but I was really interested if you can do it because I couldn't do it.

Comment: CSS variables are not variables, they are CSS **custom properties**. As such, they can only be assigned to existing CSS properties as values.

Comment: @maik if it is just two cases then create two rules for it and let specifity come into play.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only place where you can use **CSS custom properties** (which are *not* "variables"!) is in **declarations**, after the `:`. This also means that unfortunately you cannot use these custom properties in selectors, or in media queries.

That is also the reason why people really should stop calling them CSS "variables".

You can, however, manipulate styles using Javascript:

```js
const dynamicStyles = document.getElementById('dynamicStyles');

const n = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--n');

dynamicStyles.textContent = `
div p:nth-child(${n}) {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
`;
```

```css
:root {
  --n: 3;
}
```

```html
<style id="dynamicStyles"></style>
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand why this is not possible in CSS, consider this example. what would be the color of the third p element?

```html
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
</div>
```

```css
:root {
  --n: 3;
}
p {
  background: cyan;
}
p:nth-child(var(--n)) {
  background: green;
  :root:has(&) {
    --n: 1;
  }
}
```

If --n evaluates to 3 then the third p element color is green and --n evaluates to 1. Which means that the third p element color is cyan and --n evaluates to 3. And repeat.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that with pure CSS, but you can try to write a JS function to do so.

This function:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--n');
```

Will get you '3' as described in your :root{}

Now, since you can't put js in your css, you have to do all of this in your HTML file. So your job is to wrap an html style tag around the variable that you get with this function:

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById('custom-container'); //Select the div container

  node.innerHTML('<style> #custom-container p:nth-child('); //Wrap style around the variable

  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--n'); //get your variable, in this case '3'

  node.innerHTML('){background: green;padding: 10px;}</style>'); // Close the wrapping and define the style
</script>

<div id="custom-container"> <!-- Mark your div container with and ID -->
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot assign incomplete HTML to `innerHTML`, which by the way, **is not a function, but a property**. Also your snippet throws an error  `"message": "Script error.",`.